# Parse string from environment variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, environment-variables

I have a API key stored in the `.env` file (this has a structure of `NAME=key`. The key in question is a Firebase private key which has a multiline format, something like this:

```
"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\randomletters\nrandomletters\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

It's originally saved in a JSON file but I needed to store it in a .env file to include it in a Glitch project. I enclosed it in `""`but when I try to import it in my Node module using `process.env.NAME` it looks like a string but without formatting (no new line, instead `\n` is printed) and when I submit it to Firebase it is not accepted.

How can I transform that long unformatted String into a multiline String in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `\n`s with new lines with using the `replace()` method:

```
escaped.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
```